# Understanding the recursive CTE termination check

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, recursion, common-table-expression

In this sqlfiddle...

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b6587/6

I am getting the following error....

> The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted
>   before statement completion.

I understand that there needs to be a "termination check" in the where clause of the second select of the CTE.  Even if you uncomment the WHERE clause I get the same error.

I am just trying to understand 1) why it is needed at all...after all each order row has a relationship to each customer row and 2) since a "termination check" IS required what would that look like to get this example to work.

BTW, the output I would like to see for this query is as follows.

```
1,'George', 'Patton','',''
1,'','','<some date>', 'tank'
1,'','','<some date>', 'plane'
2,'Lewie', 'Puller','',''
2,'','','<some date>', 'Rifle'
2,'','','<some date>', 'Hand Grenade'
```

By the way, feel free to comment on other ways to get this kind of result (without using a recursive cte) but also without using a cursor or temp table.  I would like to do this with a set-based operation.

**EDIT**

For the record, I know a join would work but I had a reason for asking about recursion.  To give you context, I am working on a result set that is an EXPORT file.  Each row is only one column called LINE.  Furthermore, the export file needs to output in the order of my example...details need to be under header rows and that pattern needs to repeat...header/details ... header/details.  I thought that maybe recursion could solve this problem.  But I know simple join could solve it too as long as I can get the rows into the correct order...header / detail ... header / detail, maybe by having some way to do a column for sorting that numbers the output in the right way.

My export will NOT be depending on the calling app to format the data...the stored procedure needs to format the data.

Comment: Why are you using recursion here? IT's just going to endlessly cycle looking up the same customer number into the order table over and over and over and over and over and over again. Seems like a simple join would do whatever it is you are trying to do as there is nothing hierarchical about this data. Check out [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b6587/9) to use "depth" to track recursive steps and limit the recursion to 20.

Comment: It's going past the maximum number of recursions, which by default is 100. This is due to a query issue that you have-- it's an infinite recursion as @JNevill stated

Comment: Any feed back seth?

Comment: @scsimon, thanks for your answer.  My question lacked context.  I have edited the answer to provide some context.  I intentionally left my sqlfiddle very simple so that the recursion question could be addressed.  My real query actually does have some depth to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a better example using dates. Assume we want to build a table of dates. 1 row for every month for the year 2017. We create a `@startDate` as the anchor and `@endDate` as the terminator. We set these to 12 months apart, since we want a single year. Then, the recursion will add one month via the `DATEADD` function to the `@startDate` until the terminator is met in the `WHERE` clause. We know it will take 11 recursions to hit 12 months... that is, 11 months + the start date. If we set the `MAXRECURSION` to anything less than 11, then it will fail since 11 are needed to fulfill the `WHERE`clause in our recursive `CTE`, that is the terminator..

```
declare @startDate datetime = '20170101'
declare @endDate datetime = '20171201'

;WITH Months
as
(
    SELECT @startDate as TheDate       --anchor
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, TheDate)  --recursive
    FROM Months
    WHERE TheDate < @endDate           --terminator... i.e. continue until this condition is met

)


SELECT * FROM Months OPTION (MAXRECURSION 10) --change this to 11
```

For your query, a simple join would suffice.

```
select 
  firstName
  ,lastName
  ,orderDate
  ,productID
from
  customers c
inner join
  orders o on o.customerID = c.id
```

However, I see that you are trying to return this in an odd format, which should be handled in what ever reporting application you are using. This would get you close without recursion.

```
with cte as(
select 
  firstName
  ,lastName
  ,orderDate
  ,productID
  ,dense_rank() over(order by c.id) as RN
from
  customers c
inner join
  orders o on o.customerID = c.id)


select distinct
  firstName
  ,lastName
  ,null
  ,null
  ,RN
from 
  cte
union all
select
  ''
  ,''
  ,orderDate
  ,productID
  ,RN
from 
  cte
order by RN, firstName desc
```

Comment: ,looking at my sqlfiddle, can you get sql fiddle to return in the order I am requesting?  Your union would return all "headers" and then all "details".  the ORDER is really the imortant thing in this question...header/details ... header/details.  I thought recursion "might" solve this problem.

Comment: I'm confused @SethSpearman. My cte with union returns your exact results.

Comment: sorry I was looking for a fiddle.  The one in the comments above was not from you which I didn't notice...but sure enough your code does work.  Here it is in a fiddle...  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b6587/36

Comment: I'll have to check out that dense_rank() function.  But thanks...awesome solution.