# Stop query after X recursive loops

Tags: sql-server, recursive-query

I have a recursive query. The query works in most of the cases only when there is an infinite loop I want to get some results back from the database instead of the

> The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement
>   completion.

The query looks like:

```
WITH bom ( [id],[parentNumber],[warehouse],[sequenceNumber] 
                    ,[childNumber],[childDescription],[qtyRequired],[childItemClass] 
                    ,[childItemType],[scrapFactor],[bubbleNumber] ,[operationNumber] 
                    ,[effectivityDate],[discontinuityDate],[companyID]) AS (
                    select * from [products].[BillOfMaterial] where parentNumber IN ('XXXXXXXXXX')
                     and companyID = '0'UNION ALL 
                    select c.* from bom b INNER JOIN [products].[BillOfMaterial] c on b.childNumber = c.parentNumber  and c.companyID = '0')
                     SELECT distinct * FROM bom
```

So I want to change the query so  that I can fix the issue above and give some levels of the data back. Normally the tree is not deeper then 5 levels.

Is this possible in Sql server recursive queries?

Comment: You can use OPTION (MAXRECURSION 2) after this line                      SELECT distinct * FROM bom

Comment: @FadySaad That wouldn't do anything but make his error message say `2` instead of `100`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's an `OPTION` to do what you're wanting, but you could create a variable to hold the maximum number of times you want the recursion to occur, and reference it in the query:

```
Declare @MaxLevel Int = 5;

With bom (id, parentNumber, warehouse, sequenceNumber, childNumber, childDescription, qtyRequired, childItemClass, childItemType, scrapFactor, bubbleNumber,
          operationNumber, effectivityDate, discontinuityDate, companyID, Level
         )
As (Select *,
           1 As Level
    From   products.BillOfMaterial
    Where  parentNumber In ( 'XXXXXXXXXX' )
           And companyID = '0'
    Union All
    Select c.*,
           Level + 1 As Level
    From   bom b
    Inner Join products.BillOfMaterial c
        On b.childNumber = c.parentNumber
           And c.companyID = '0'
    Where  Level < @MaxLevel
   )
Select Distinct *
From   bom;
```

Here's a working example with dates:

```
Declare @MaxLevel Int = 5;

;With Cte As
(
    Select  Convert(Date, GetDate()) As Date,
            1 As Level
    Union All
    Select  DateAdd(Day, 1, Date) As Date,
            Level + 1 As Level
    From    Cte
    Where   Level < @MaxLevel
)
Select  *
From    Cte
```

> Results

```
Date        Level
2017-09-14  1
2017-09-15  2
2017-09-16  3
2017-09-17  4
2017-09-18  5
```

Comment: Good answer. I would explain the anchor, recursive part, and terminator since i think OP doesn't understand that. [I did something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45889108/6167855) for someone else. +1

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should do it:

```
WITH bom ( [id],[parentNumber],[warehouse],[sequenceNumber] 
                    ,[childNumber],[childDescription],[qtyRequired],[childItemClass] 
                    ,[childItemType],[scrapFactor],[bubbleNumber] ,[operationNumber] 
                    ,[effectivityDate],[discontinuityDate],[companyID])
 AS (
    select *, 1 as Depth
     from [products].[BillOfMaterial]
     where parentNumber IN ('XXXXXXXXXX')
      and companyID = '0'
    union all select c.*, b.Depth + 1 as Depth
     from bom b
      INNER JOIN [products].[BillOfMaterial] c
       on b.childNumber = c.parentNumber
        and c.companyID = '0'
     --where b.Depth < xx
    )
 SELECT distinct * FROM bom
  --where Depth < xx
```

I haven't tested this precise code, and am not sure which `where` clause should be used, but I have done queries like this before. The idea is to put an arbitrary counter in that tracks depth xx, and cut the query off when it reaches that depth.